# Prove that $\{(x,y): x < y\}$ is an open set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Equivalently we can show that $D^c := \{(x,y): x \geq y\}$ is closed, since an open set is the complement of a closed set. A set is closed if it contains all limit points.

So let $x$ be a limit point of $D^c$. Then there is a sequence $x_n$ in $D^c$ for all natural numbers $n$, such that $x_n \rightarrow x$. Since $x_n \in D^c$ for all $n$, $x_n \geq y$ $\implies$ $x \geq y$. Thus, $x \in D^c$. This proves $D^c$ is closed and so it follows that $D := \{(x,y): x < y\}$ is open. QED.

I am wondering if my proof is correct. Thanks.

Comment: Are you in a metric space? Is this $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric?

Comment: Yes this is $R^2$

Comment: Your proof is flawed, elements of $D^c$ are couples, so your sequence should look like $(x_n,y_n)$ and converge to some $(x,y)$. That implies that $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$. Letting $n\to \infty$ in $x_n\geq y_n$ yields $x\geq y$, hence $(x,y)\in D^c$

Comment: Ahh I see now, thank you so much. Is everything else okay?

Comment: @Javier the rest is ok. I wrote a different proof below.

Comment: @Andres I don't believe we have spoken of what it means for a set to be degenerate in my class, so I don't know if we can assume it's not degenerate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different proof:

$f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R, (x,y)\to x-y$ is continous (linear).

$D=f^{-1}((-\infty,0)$) is the preimage of an open set, and is therefore open.

Comment: This is nice. Do you think what I put below works. Its a little different.

Answer (score 2):

Fix $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $A_{y_0} = \{(x,y_0): x<y_0\}$. Can you show this is open? This is immediate since $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual metric is Hausdorff. Also remember to give this set the subspace topology . then you'll notice that it is homeomorphic to a open ray. Once you do this then notice that;

$$D = \bigcup_{y_0 \in \mathbb{R}} A_{y_0} $$

Is an arbitrary union of open sets, hence open.